# Best practice to creating a phone based application using GWT which will run on both iPhone and android

Tags: gwt

I am going to develop a GWT application for one of the project 
I need it to be running on Android and Iphone as well

One option i see is PhoneGap ,but not sure if this is the current best practice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to [mgwt](http://www.m-gwt.com/) and their phonegap wrapper.  You can also use [Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/) in combination with GWT, FYI the new Inbox app from Google is about 70% GWT code, 30% Closure.